# need help calling text_a(), that was initially declared in foo(), inside the called function foo()

Tags: javascript

I am creating code similar to this:

```js
function foo(type,callback) {
 if(type === "a") {
  function text_a() {
   return "a";
  }
 }else if(type === "b") {
  function text_b() {
   return "b";
  }
 }else if(type === "c") {
  function text_c() {
   return "c";
  }
 }
 if(typeof callback === "function") callback();
}

foo("a",function() {
 console.log(text_a());
});
```

I want the function `text_a()` inside `foo()` to only be available when the type is equal to the relevant type and is called inside the `foo()` function. However this does not work. I keep getting an error message saying that `text_a()` is not defined, which makes no sense because when the `foo` function is called it should also declare the `text_a` function if the type is "a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save a reference to the function and pass it to the callback..

eg.

```js
function foo(type,callback) {
 var fn;
 if(type === "a") {
  fn = function text_a() {
   return "a";
  }
 }else if(type === "b") {
  fn = function text_b() {
   return "b";
  }
 }else if(type === "c") {
  fn = function text_c() {
   return "c";
  }
 }
 if(typeof callback === "function") callback(fn);
}

foo("a",function(fn) {
 console.log(fn());
});

foo("b",function(fn) {
 console.log(fn());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!